# Parameter from angular not mapped into C# object

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have a problem with mapping one parameter from my angular `$http` call to C# method.

On a server side I use MVC. On a client is angular. I've tried to debug with developer tools inside Chrome and everything was fine, without errors.

Parameter which doesn't map (stays `null`) is `cORAM_NTO`. I've checked in console that `$scope.Note` is filled with value.

But, on the server side value for `cORAM_NTO` is `null`.

Here is call on client side (angular):

```
$scope.SaveModal = function (event) 
{
    $http(
    {
        method: "POST",
        url: $scope.UrlSaveDataCAORAM,
        data: 
        {
            iORAM_KEY: $scope.CurrentORAM_KEY,
            dORAM_DSE: $scope.SellDate,
            cORAM_MPA: $scope.WayPayment,
            cORAM_NIC: $scope.ConfirmationNumber,
            cORAM_ANB: $scope.AccountNumber,
            dORAM_DBE: $scope.DateUse,
            decORAM_VAU: $scope.AmountUse,
            cORAM_ANB2: $scope.AccountAmountUseRest,
            dORAM_DBE2: $scope.DateUseRest,
            decORAM_VAU2: $scope.AmountUseRest,
            cORAM_NTO: $scope.Note
        }
    }).then(function success(response) 
    {

    }, function failure() 
    {

    })
}
```

Here is class for DTO_CAORAM (parameter cORAM_NTO is last):

```
public class DTO_CAORAM
{
    public int? iORAM_KEY { get; set; }
    public int? iORAS_KEY { get; set; }
    public int? iMEST_KEY { get; set; }
    public int? iUNIT_KEY { get; set; }

    public string cORAM_SRT { get; set; }
    public string cORAM_STA { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dORAM_DAT { get; set; }
    public double? decORAM_QUA { get; set; }

    public string cORAM_UNI { get; set; }
    public double? decORAM_NET { get; set; }
    public double? decORAM_GRO { get; set; }


    public DateTime? dORAM_DSE { get; set; }
    public string cORAM_MPA { get; set; }
    public string cORAM_NIC { get; set; }
    public string cORAM_ANB { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dORAM_DBE { get; set; }
    public double? decORAM_VAU { get; set; }
    public string cORAM_ANB2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dORAM_DBE2 { get; set; }
    public double? decORAM_VAU2 { get; set; }


    public string cMEST_CDO2 { get; set; }
    public int? iMERC_KEY { get; set; }
    public int? iACCO_KEY { get; set; }
    public int? iORAC_KEY { get; set; }

    public string cORAM_NTO { get; set; }
}
```

And finally function on server side (all params are mapped except cORAM_NTO):

```
public void SaveDataCAORAM(DTO_CAORAM dto)
{


}
```

Here is POST request recorded from a network tab:

```
    dto
:
{iORAM_KEY: "160000008", dORAM_DSE: "01.06.2016", cORAM_MPA: "fsfsfsdf", cORAM_NIC: "6666",…}
cORAM_ANB
:
"jjjgfhgfhg"
cORAM_ANB2
:
"rtttttt"
cORAM_MPA
:
"fsfsfsdf"
cORAM_NIC
:
"6666"
cORAM_NTO
:
"notest test"
dORAM_DBE
:
"02.07.2016"
dORAM_DBE2
:
"03.08.2016"
dORAM_DSE
:
"01.06.2016"
decORAM_VAU
:
"54444,0000"
decORAM_VAU2
:
"7777,0000"
iORAM_KEY
:
"160000008"
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What happens when you debug? Have you already tried to look via F12 developer console if there happens any angular error? Or debug with f12 developer console through your angular code and see if variable is really set!

Comment: I'm already surprised that the rest of the parameters is set... Can anybody do something with those names that you are using? Any reason why you don't choose for [camelCase and PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx)? What kind of serverside mechanism do you have implemented? Do you have a custom formatter?

Comment: Yes of course I've tried with F12 - value for $scope.Note is set. No errors.

Comment: Can you show the post request from the network tab?

Comment: I would like to but I don't know how to see post request in network tab?

Comment: OK, I've made it. I've added recorded POST request to my question.

Comment: The built in JSON formatters in MVC assume you will follow C# and JSON conventions (PascalCase and camelCase for property names respectively). You could dig into the JSON parser code to figure out what's going on, but my first guess would be your strange naming scheme is the problem.

It also seems like it might be really good idea from the standpoint of readability to follow the same conventions the rest of the world uses. (PascalCase and camelCase, no Hungarian Notation).
c.f. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx

Comment: @NickBailey - all params are named the same way. All except one are mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've renamed parameter cORAM_NTO to cORAM_NTO1 and tried that. It worked. Than I renamed it back and it worked with cORAM_NTO.